# how to convert the data coming from a column in a table to a GUID

Tags: vb.net

Basically i am creating a variable of a new type of object and in the sub new constructor it can take in a datarow or a GUID. when i call it i am trying to pass the UUID field of the datarow but it says there is a conversion issue with system.object to GUID and also says option strict on disallows....object to system.data.datarow. below is where im calling it where dr.Item("UUID")

```
        Public Shared ReadOnly Property GetApprovers As List(Of Trident.Core.User)
        Get
            Dim dbConn As New Trident.Core.DBConnection
            Dim sql As String
            Dim apprs As New List(Of Trident.Core.User)

            sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Approver From ***.Core.ApprovalAlternates "

            Dim ds = dbConn.FillDataSet(sql)
            For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                Dim tmpAppr As New Trident.Core.User(dr.Item("UUID"))
                apprs.Add(tmpAppr)
            Next
            Return apprs
        End Get
    End Property
```

and my class that has the constructors so u know what it takes in. i cant change those as the world will break if i do. can i cast the parameter or something?

```
Public Sub New()
    _IsNew = True
End Sub

Public Sub New(datarow As DataRow)
    _IsNew = False
    Load(datarow)
End Sub

Public Sub New(id As Guid)
    m_UUID = id
    _IsNew = False
    Init()
End Sub
```

Comment: `dr.Item("UUID")` returns an Object.  You may know what it contains but that doesnt convert it for the code.  Parse the contents to a GUID and pass that

Comment: so i made a variable As New Guid and in my For each loop i have tempGUID.add(dr.Item("UUID")) but add is not a part of system.Guid and i cant use += and i cant use tempGuid.Guid.parse(dr.Item("UUID")) how would i do this ?

Comment: What database are you using and what is the exact type the GUID is stored as?  A GUID is a NET thing, and not all DBs have a type it is convertible to.  `UUID` sounds like a replication ID.